# Python multiprocessing not printing example code to stdout

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-3.8

I'm copying this code exactly from the Python [multiprocessing Process documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

I'd expect that when it's run in IDLE, I'd see "hello bob" come back.  Instead I get nothing.  Inspecting the p variable shows a normal exit code.

```
============= RESTART: C:/Users/Hoofran/Desktop/DemoMultiProcess.py ============
>>> p
<Process name='Process-1' pid=17268 parent=18116 stopped exitcode=0>
>>>
```

Is this how multiprocessing is supposed to work, suppressing stdout?  If so why doesn't documentation mention that? What am I missing here?

Comment: The output looks like you are running this from, I dunno, some IDE or notebook? Please [edit] to show us details about this.

Comment: @tripleee OP says this is run from IDLE, a python IDE

Comment: Code is working, [in online compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/BJe8z9wGw). What ever the problem is, it is in IDE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This appears to be an IDLE specific issue. Replicated issue across multiple machines. Running in IDLE python 3.8.3 doesn't print any rows, but running from command line prints as expected.

```
PS C:\Users\ryan.mcgrath\Desktop> cat .\simpleMultiprocessing.py
from multiprocessing import Process

def f(name):
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()


PS C:\Users\ryan.mcgrath\Desktop> python .\simpleMultiprocessing.py
hello bob
PS C:\Users\ryan.mcgrath\Desktop> python
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```